# $\mathbb{C}\left(z\right)\left[\left[w\right]\right]\cap\mathbb{C}\left(w\right)\left[\left[z\right]\right]\overset{?}{=}\mathbb{C}\left(z,w\right)$

Tags: formal-power-series

Consider the formal power series: $$f\left(z,w\right)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{m,n}z^{m}w^{n}$$

for some complex coefficients $c_{m,n}$. Defining:

$$\alpha_{m}\left(w\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{m,n}w^{n}$$
$$\beta_{n}\left(z\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}c_{m,n}z^{m}$$

we can write: $$f\left(z,w\right)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{m,n}z^{m}w^{n}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\alpha_{m}\left(w\right)z^{m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta_{n}\left(z\right)w^{n}$$

As such:

(1) If all the $\alpha_{m}$s and $\beta_{n}$s are rational functions of $w$ and $z$, respectively, is $f$ itself then necessarily a rational function of $z$ and $w$?

(2) (Generalization to power series in $d$ indeterminates) Working with a formal power series over $\mathbb{C}$ in $d$ indeterminates $z_{1},\ldots,z_{d}$:

$$f\left(z_{1},\ldots,z_{d}\right)=\sum_{n_{1}=0}^{\infty}\cdots\sum_{n_{d}=0}^{\infty}c_{n_{1},\ldots,n_{d}}z_{1}^{n_{1}}\cdots z_{d}^{n_{d}}$$

suppose that for every $j\in\left\{ 1,\ldots,d\right\}$, the series:

$$\sum_{n_{1}=0}^{\infty}\cdots\sum_{n_{j-1}=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n_{j+1}=0}^{\infty}\cdots\sum_{n_{d}=0}^{\infty}c_{n_{1},\ldots,n_{j-1},n,n_{j+1}\ldots n_{d}}z_{1}^{n_{1}}\cdots z_{j-1}^{n_{j-1}}z_{j+1}^{n_{j+1}}\cdots z_{d}^{n_{d}}$$

is a rational function of $ z_{1},\ldots,z_{j-1},z_{j+1}\ldots,z_{d}$ for all $n\geq0$. Is that sufficient to force $f$ to be a rational function of  $z_{1},\ldots,z_{d}$?

Comment: Not related to your final questions, but related to the question in your title, is $1/z \in \mathbb{C}(w)[[z]]\text{?}$

Comment: That is an excellent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $e^{zw}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(zw)^n}{n!}$. Each coefficient, as a $z$ series and as a $w$ series, is rational, but $e^{zw}$ isn't.

Comment: Damn. I should have seen that one coming. That being said, the case I'm *really* interested in is what happens when the coefficients take on only finitely many distinct values. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @MCS What exactly does it mean 'the coefficients take on only finitely many values'?

Comment: It means that there is a finite, non-empty set $S\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ so that for every $ \left(n_{1},\ldots,n_{d}\right)\in\mathbb{N}^{d}$, the coefficient $c_{n_{1},\ldots,n_{d}}$ is an element of $S$. The particular case I'm studying is when $S=\left\{ 0,1\right\} $

Comment: @MCS Yes, if you put many gaps in between the non-zero coefficients the function will be transcendental. Like $\sum_n z^{n!}w^{n!}$.